# What does "Pareto-inferior to x" mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology, mathematics

I want to translate one chapter of a book from English. Who can explain to me what is "Pareto-inferior to x" at the end of third page? I think it is a mathematical term. I got some ideas about what it can be in my main language but I'm not sure it is. I think it is something like "Limit inferior of x" or smth. But the writer chose to write "to" instead of "of". It's a little bit confusing. Moreover, might it be an Economic term of smth?
Thanks in advance.

[image: first page]

[image: second page]

[image: third page]

Comment: Not my specialist subject, but apparently [Pareto efficiency or Pareto optimality is a state of allocation of resources from which it is impossible to reallocate so as to make any one individual or preference criterion better off without making at least one individual or preference criterion worse off.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) My guess is that "Pareto-inferior" is effectively a "one-off" coinage meaning ***sub-optimal; inferior according to Pareto's definition of a fully optimal marketplace*** (where prices are set at such a level that any change would be "worse").

Comment: (In the cited context, ***X** = the **optimum** state of allocation of resources according to Pareto's criteria*.)

Comment: Thank you very much) Now I understand what the writer intended to mean.
Can I ask a new question very quick?

Comment: This *current* question might get "closed" because it's about "domain-specific terminology", but unless and until that happens, I don't mind responding briefly in comments. (Except I have to go out briefly, but should be back again within the next hour or so.)

Comment: Consider "As a result they would not be expected to occur in a market system."
What does "Would not be expected" mean? It means no one wants it to be happened? Or is this and unexpected event?

Comment: Depending on the exact context, "Would not be expected" *might* imply "No-one ***wants*** it to happen*. But literally speaking it just means it's not considered ***likely***. Whether that unlikely outcome is desirable or not depends entirely on the specific context. In *your* context, it seems to be assumed that the marketplace is reasonably well organised, so grossly sub-optimal "Pareto-deficient" arrangements would be unlikely to arise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about domain-specific terminology.

Comment: Is there really a rule here about "domain-specific terminology"?   Can someone point to that?  I'm not seeing it in the Help or FAQ...

Answer (score 2):

"Pareto-inferior" is a technical term from economics with a rigorous mathematical definition, so it's not a short answer! But, as briefly as possible:

"Pareto-inferior" compares two allocations A, and B.

If you can change A (by changing some of the individual/atomic allocations) to A' so that some extra utility is realized for one or more individuals without decreasing any other individuals' utilities, that is called a "pareto improvement", and the size of the pareto improvement is the difference between the total realized utility of A' and the total realized utility of A (summed over individuals).

If the maximum sized Pareto improvement possible in A is strictly larger in size than the maximum sized Pareto improvement possible in B, then A is **Pareto-inferior** to B.

If the largest sized improvement to A is zero (ie. no improvements possible), A is called Pareto-optimal; a Pareto-optimal allocation is not Pareto-inferior to any other.

The "common-sense" way of thinking about this is that if an allocation A is Pareto-inferior to an allocation B, A "wastes more wealth" than B; there is more potential for changing the wealth distribution in A so that some people are better off and those that are not better off are indifferent to the change.

Answer (score 0):

The text appears to be defining *pareto-inferior* by way of exposition.

Another name for

> "The changes that make everyone in the two person society worse off, that would not be expected to occur in a market system"

which is detailed above, is

> *pareto-inferior*

Comment: This isn't quite right.  First, "pareto-inferior" functions as an adjective and your definition functions as a noun.  That alone should show you that you're not defining the term correctly.  Second, Pareto inefficiencies /are/ expected to occur in market systems.  There are a famous group of theorems in economics that say ''under certain conditions'' market systems ''tend to approach an equilibrium'' where no pareto inefficiencies occur - but this is very different than what you claim above.